# SQL Order By month name chronologically instead of alphabetically

Tags: mysql, sql, phpmyadmin, sql-order-by

I would like to get the month names to be in chronological order instead of alphabetically ordered. 
Here is my Sql code.

```
SELECT month, sum(total) 
FROM (SELECT MONTHNAME(terms) AS month, COUNT(DISTINCT project_num) AS total  
      FROM projects 
      WHERE terms >= '2017/01/01'
      GROUP BY MONTH(terms) 
      UNION 
      SELECT MONTHNAME(terms) AS month, COUNT(DISTINCT project_num) AS total 
      FROM archive
      WHERE terms >= '2017/01/01' 
      GROUP BY MONTH(terms) 
     ) AS test
GROUP BY month
ORDER BY month
```

The output of the code above looks like [This](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dxXwY.png)

I would like it to be:

> January
>
> February
>
> March
>
> ...
>
> ...

Comment: Select `terms` too in your subquery and then order by it

Comment: I used this and it worked

Comment: I want something like January-2018, January-2017, February-2018, February-2017, February-2016...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Order the month as int to order it. `With MONTH(STR_TO_DATE(month, '%M'))`

```
SELECT month, sum(total) 
    FROM (SELECT MONTHNAME(terms) AS month, COUNT(DISTINCT project_num) AS total  
          FROM projects 
          WHERE terms >= '2017/01/01'
          GROUP BY MONTH(terms) 
          UNION 
          SELECT MONTHNAME(terms) AS month, COUNT(DISTINCT project_num) AS total 
          FROM archive
          WHERE terms >= '2017/01/01' 
          GROUP BY MONTH(terms) 
         ) AS test
    GROUP BY month
    ORDER BY MONTH(STR_TO_DATE(month, '%M'))
```

Answer (score 0):

You can leverage the temp table

```
with temp as(
SELECT month, sum(total) as total
FROM (SELECT MONTHNAME(terms) AS month, COUNT(DISTINCT project_num) AS total  
      FROM projects 
      WHERE terms >= '2017/01/01'
      GROUP BY MONTH(terms) 
      UNION 
      SELECT MONTHNAME(terms) AS month, COUNT(DISTINCT project_num) AS total 
      FROM archive
      WHERE terms >= '2017/01/01' 
      GROUP BY MONTH(terms) 
     ) AS test
GROUP BY month
)
select * from temp order by month
```

Answer (score 0):

If you're using SQL Server database:

```
SELECT month, sum(total) 
FROM (SELECT MONTHNAME(terms) AS month, COUNT(DISTINCT project_num) AS total  
      FROM projects 
      WHERE terms >= '2017/01/01'
      GROUP BY MONTH(terms) 
      UNION 
      SELECT MONTHNAME(terms) AS month, COUNT(DISTINCT project_num) AS total 
      FROM archive
      WHERE terms >= '2017/01/01' 
      GROUP BY MONTH(terms) 
     ) AS test
GROUP BY month
ORDER BY month(month + ' 1 2014')
```